# Does Spring Security SAML Extension or spring-security-saml2-service-provider work for Non-Spring Java Web Apps?

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, azure-entra-id

With Reference to spring-security-saml2-service-provider here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-saml2-service-provider
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/main/saml2/saml2-service-provider

and the older Spring Security SAML Extension here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf

Does anyone know if it's possible to implement SAML with Microsoft Entra ID Enterprise Apps for Java Web apps that were built without Spring (aka Non-Spring Web Apps)?

I do not have access to the Java Source code as these are war files that once deployed the only files I can modify are web.xml, server.xml, .properties files, and context.xml, etc.

Using OpenJDK11 with Tomcat 9 or TomEE as the servlet container:
https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.20%2B8/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.20_8.zip

Thank you for any insight.

Looking for insight.
Tried the sample, but seems it's expecting access to source code:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/login